# What are the historic definitions of the word dragon?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Today, the term dragon is universally used for mythical, non-existent creatures that resemble dinosaurs in some ways. I thought I heard once from someone quoting a dictionary from 1600 something that the definition was "A very rare, but still living creature". This implies that the author thought that dragons were a real thing.

I don't expect there to be much overlap today from its ancient use because there is a lot of entertainment fiction written on the subject since 1900.

I want to know how the word has been used in the past and if there were descriptions of what a dragon actually is/was from before 1850's, when the word "dinosaur" was coined. I am also particularly interested if the people of those times thought the creatures were real.

Comment: I think this is an extremely interesting question, but it has [nothing to do with English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_in_Greek_mythology).

Comment: @PeterShor Well, I realize that there is a translation for "dragon" in many cultures and languages, past and present, but I want the question to focus exclusively on English use. I want to verify if that 1600's definition is true.

Comment: By looking in Shakespeare, you can see that in his time, people thought that dragons had wings, tails, scales, were fierce, and breathed fire. This isn't too different from today's definition.

Comment: @PeterShor Okay. I'm more concerned with people thinking that they were real.

Comment: @fredsbend Good news, there **are** real [dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_Dragon).

Comment: I suspect the answer may be significantly different than what is mentioned to date. I came here because of a phrase written by Sir Francis Bacon about the motions of celestial bodies. He wrote about those who describe their supposed motion in "perfect circles, spirals and dragons." This indicates some kind of shape... but certainly nothing resembling I can envision as a "dragon." SO... perhaps a bigger mystery than we know?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the word *dragon* was used for living creatures in the past.

Here is the obsolete definition from *OED*:

> A huge serpent or snake; a python. *Obs.* (exc. in etymol. use).

The earliest citation in *OED* is from c1220:

> Ðe dragunes one ne stiren nout..oc daren stille in here pit.
>
> <sub>Bestiary 759</sub>

Comment: Here is an illustrative book for the history of dragons: https://books.google.ca/books?id=gSUKq16UxMIC&pg=PA8&dq#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2):

This goes very far back in time indeed - right to the Indo-European era. There is a book that talks about the common features of Indo-European speech and poetry - still to be seen in kindred languages such as Greek, Sanskrit, Old Irish, Latin, English, etc.

It's titled [How to kill a dragon](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/398718.How_to_Kill_a_Dragon), using the dragon as one theme that was common to the poetries of nations that inherited this common culture.

Of course, this doesn't directly answer your question, but this question, interesting as it is, is the topic of a book or two, like the one I recommend.

Comment: Interesting but not really an answer for the OP's question unless you can include excerpts from the book that directly answer *"how the word has been used in the past and if there were descriptions of what a dragon actually is/was from before 1850's"*.

Comment: Sorry, I agree, but it's a rather long answer. My current answer exhorts the asker to look for the book, or excerpts of it.

Comment: Except this isn't a resource recommendation site, it's an English language usage site where we want all the nitty gritty in the answer. :-)

Comment: Ok you can shoot me now :-)

Comment: No shooting, just edjumacating! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Lifted from [Scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96167/why-model-smaug-after-a-cat/96175#96175); *Why model Smaug after a cat?* Excerpt from Wad Cheber's answer, mentioning the earliest 'definition' of *dragon* that I'm aware of:

The Chinese dragon appears to have had a significant influence on the Japanese dragon.  The Han Dynasty (206 BCE - 220 CE) scholar Wang Fu [wrote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_dragon), of traditional Chinese dragon imagery,

> (recording Chinese myths that *long* dragons had nine anatomical resemblances):
>
> The people paint the dragon's shape with a **horse's head** and a **snake's tail**. Further, there are expressions as 'three joints' and '**nine resemblances**' (of the dragon), to wit: from head to shoulder, from shoulder to breast, from breast to tail. These are the joints; as to the nine resemblances, they are the following: his **antlers resemble those of a stag**, his **head that of a camel**, his **eyes those of a demon**, his **neck that of a snake**, his **belly that of a clam** (shen, 蜃), his **scales those of a carp**, his **claws those of an eagle**, his **soles those of a tiger**, his **ears those of a cow**. Upon his head he has a thing like a broad eminence (a big lump), called [chimu] (尺木). If a dragon has no [chimu], he cannot ascend to the sky.

Answer (score 0):

The Webster’s Dictionary of 1828 has some interesting definitions that vary quite drastically.

> DRAGON, noun [Latin , Gr., G.]
>
> 1. A kind of winged serpent, much celebrated in the romances of the middle ages.
> 2. A fiery, shooting meteor, or imaginary serpent.
>
> > Swift, swift, ye dragons of the night! That dawning may bear the ravens eye.
>
> 1. A fierce, violent person, male or female; as, this man or woman is a dragon
> 2. A constellation of the northern hemisphere. [See Draco.]
>
> DRAGON, noun A genus of animals, the Draco. They have four legs, a cylindrical tail, and membranaceous wings, radiated like the fins of a flying-fish.

The first definition acknowledges a fictional creature, but the last seems to talk about a non-fictional creature. To me it’s possible that a creature used to exist called a dragon however tales were made that exaggerated what it was creating the fictional dragon we know today. A similar thing happened with the idea of Unicorns.

Comment: _[Draco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draco_(lizard))_ is indeed a genus of flying lizards in the family _Agamidae_.  Webster's definition is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

The description of Leviathan God inspires in Job 41 (including v21:

- *Its breath sets coals ablaze, and flames dart from its mouth*

[[NIV; Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%2041&version=NIV)]) indicates to fundamentalists that fire-breathing creatures once co-existed with man. The first independent clause precludes a metaphorical interpretation. See, for instance, [David Guzik's commentary](https://enduringword.com/bible-commentary/job-41/).

National Geographic once had an article theorising about whether a head cavity in a certain dinosaur might have contained auto-combusting (in air) phosphines. And in fact the Septuagint translated into Greek between thethird century BCE and the 2nd century BCE) even uses the word δρακωον (dragon) for Leviathan.

The description given in Job (including that this creature was feared by sailors) is quite detailed, but (pictorial) illustrations will be fanciful rather than accurate.